# Printing correct output in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this following code

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello"
echo "enter salutation $abc"
Read -r abc
If [ "$abc" = "1" ] 
Then 
Echo "hiii"
Elif [ "$abc" = "2"]
Then
Echo "no hi"
Fi
Echo "enter name $xyz"
Read -r xyz
If [ "$xyz" = "1" ]
Then 
Echo "Chris"
Elif ["$xyz" = "2" ] 
Then 
Echo "Morris"
Fi
Echo "final data"
Echo " you entered salutation as " "$abc"
Echo "you entered name as "$xyz"
```

Out put comes as

```
Hello
Enter the number 
1
Hiii
Enter name
1
Chris 

You entered salutation as 1
You entered name as 1
```

What I want is

```
You entered salutation as hii
You entered name as chris
```

Comment: Please post your actual code. What you have shown is not valid shell script syntax and will not even run.

Comment: this is not a valid shell script. are you sure this is the correct script that you write to get that output?

Comment: Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds before asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using numbered inputs to select from pre-arranged options; in that case, when the user selects a number you can use that number to assign a variable based on the value you want.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hello"

echo "enter salutation: 1 for hiii and 2 for no hi"
read -r salutation
case $salutation in
        1) salutation="hiii";;
        2) salutation="no hi";;
        *) echo "Only 1 or 2 can be specified"; exit 1;;
esac


echo "enter name: 1 for Chris, and 2 for Morris"
read -r name
case $name in
        1) name="Chris";;
        2) name="Morris";;
        *) echo "Only options 1, or 2 are supported"; exit 2;;
esac


echo "final data"
echo "you entered salutation as $salutation"
echo "you entered name as $name"
```

In your conditional, you should assign the value to a variable rather than just printing it out.  Then, you can use the variable later on.

Comment: This is quite far from running as-is. (http://shellcheck.net/ will find numerous still-outstanding issues -- many of these `if` conditions will *never* result in anything but an error).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy there are _soooo_ many issues, yes.  Nonetheless this script works as the op requested on my machine :)

Comment: ...only because they're only testing a tiny subset of possible codepaths. `[ "$abc" -eq "2"]`, for example, will *never* succeed -- and `["$xyz" -eq "2" ]` doesn't even call `[` if `xyz` is nonempty.

Comment: Let me further point to the "Answer well-asked questions" section of http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Agreed.  I did the minimal required to get it to respond as the op requested with the inputs the op specified... fixing the script is an exercise for the op

Comment: Thanks for that link; that actually encourages me to spend more time on these kinds of answers, even if the specific answer to the specific question is obfuscated by vast changes (upvoted that comment)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy no need to discuss unless you want to, but this script reports no errors with shellcheck

Comment: As rewritten, this is indeed much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was not working because you were printing variables $abc and $xyz which contain a 1 or a 2, not a string. If you have more doubts, let me know.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello, enter a number for salutation:"
read -r abc
if [ $abc = 1 ] 
then 
    Salutation="hiii"
elif [ $abc = 2 ]
then
    Salutation="no hi"
fi
echo "enter number 1 or 2 for name:"
read -r xyz
if [ "$xyz" = "1" ] 
then 
    Name="Chris"
elif ["$xyz" = "2" ] 
then 
    Name="Morris"
fi
echo "final data"
echo "you entered salutation as $Salutation"
echo "you entered name as $Name"
```